Convergence of the trajectory of ODE
Consider a $C^\infty$ smooth nonconvex function $f$, and ODE
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=-x\circ\nabla f(x),\\
x(0)\in\mathbb{R}^d_{++}.
\end{cases}
$$
Here $\circ$ is elementwise product, $\mathbb{R}^d_{++}$ the set of strict positive vectors. Then, can you prove that the solution has finite length under mild condition, e.g. $f$ satisfies the Kurdyka-Łojasiewicz inequality?
We shold be careful that $x(t)$ can approach the boundary of $\mathbb{R}^d_{++}$. I believe it should be correct, as I have tried many numerical test and cannot find any counterexamples.

What is the meaning of $\circ$, given that  it is not composition? What is $\mathbb R_{++}^d$?

Hi, the $\circ$ is elementwise product, $\mathbb{R}^d_{++}$ the set of strict positive vectors. I have updated the question.

Thank you -maybe then $\cdot$ is preferable

It would also be useful to write the inequality in your case. This paper seems to be related to your problem https://mathreader.github.io/files/note_kurdyka_lojasiewicz_inequality.pdf

Thanks. I am a mathematical optimization researcher. Indeed, the dynamical system comes from an optimization problem. I have tried the KL assumption, but it is not enough.
